# Test specific error number from a Python socket exception

Tags: python, sockets

I have some python code that binds to a socket.  I catch any exception so that I can handle it.  Depending on the error, I want to do different things.  How do I know what an error number means?

For example, I want to do something like:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
   s.bind(('', 80))
except socket.error, ex
   (error_number, error_message) = ex
   if error_number==EADDRINUSE:
      print "You can't bind to that port -- someone else is using it"
   else:
      print "Unknown socket error"
```

except that I don't know what error number corresponds to EADDRINUSE.  On my Ubuntu box it is 98, on a Mac running OS X 10.5 it is 48, and on a Windows XP box it is 10048.  Is there some place where these are included in a python library?

I realize that the numbers are different because of differences in errno.h in the C layer, but I do not know where they are exposed in python.  Similarly, I assume that I can't rely on the error message being a specific string.

Also, I'm not just concerned about EADDRINUSE -- I'd like to cover other errors, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors are all defined in the [errno](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html) module in the standard library.